# Highlight css with overlap

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a very specific look for a site I'm designing and have run into a brick wall. I'd like to "highlight" `quotes` and `<h2>` tags, with the background color overlapping (similar to if you used a real highlighter).

This is an example of what I'd like to do:

[image: Intended effect of Highlighted text]

I've tried several options.

1. Trying to edit the style of the  tag,
2. using background gradients with a slight opacity, etc. and I simply cannot get it to work.

Here's my latest attempt, which looks like garbage as the gradient does not produce the look I am going for, and the background seems to be seen as one element and does not overlap on multiple lines:

```css
.highlight span { 
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e2e200,#ffff00);
    opacity:1;
    color: #fff; 
    display: inline;
    padding: 0.45rem;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider using `rgba()` notation for `background-color`.

Comment: For my answer below, you can change the '0.3' in the background-color style to something a little less transparent if you want to match exactly to the example in your post

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution:

Use `background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.3);` to make the yellow transparent

And `margin-bottom: -15px;` to make them overlap

HTML and CSS:

```css
    .highlight span { 
        background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.3);
        opacity:1;
        color: #555; 
        display: inline;
        padding: 0.45rem;
        box-decoration-break: clone;
        font-family: arial;
    }
    
    .highlight {
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
```

```html
    <h2 class = "highlight">
      <span>Test again</span>
    </h2>
    <h2 class = "highlight">
      <span>Test</span>
    </h2>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3t1qvud/

Answer (score 1):

Use background color for the text to be highlighted Ex: text inside span, and also to the container Ex: `<p>`.

Take a look at the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/harikashekhar/93qy9406/5/

```css
div {
      padding: 2em;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      line-height: 180%;
    }
    p {
      background-color: #FFFBCC;
    }
    span.highlight {
      background-color: #FFFBAA;
      padding: 0.2em;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
       <p>
           <span class="highlight">This is a text. This is a text. </span>
           This is a text. This is a text. This is a text
           <span class="highlight">This is a text. This is a text</span>
      </p>
    </div>
```